# Prove that $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Let $C=\{(x,\:y,\:z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1,\; -1<z<1\}$ and $C=\{(x,\:y,\:z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1,\; -1<z<1\}$. Define $F:C\to S$ as $$F(x,\:y,\:z)=(x\sqrt{1-z^2},\:y\sqrt{1-z^2},\:z)$$

Prove that $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

My attempt: The inverse of $F$ is given as $F^{-1}(x,\:y,\:z)=(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-z^2}},\:\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1-z^2}},\:z)$.

Now it is clear that both $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are smooth, so $F$ is diffeomorphism.

However, I figured out that my solution is incorrect. Why is my solution wrong and what is the right solution?

Any advices and hints are welcome. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A diffeomorphism is also a bijection.

Comment: @anomaly Yeah, I already know that $F$ is bijection.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'You figured out your solution is incorrect"?

In any case, note that $C$ is not a smooth manifold in the traditional sense. $F$ here is a homeomorphism that is in essence carrying the smooth structure from $S$ to $C$.